# Android ListView Disappearing (SDK 2.3.3)

Tags: android, listview

I'm attempting to develop an application for my Android device, and I seem to be having trouble. I'm trying to have a `TextView` (or another component) at the top of the `Activity`, and a `Listview` beneath it. The problem that I'm having is that if I have more than just the `ListView` in the layout, it doesn't render. So since I'm trying to have a `TextView` and `ListView`, only the `TextView` is being shown.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_string"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/list_contents" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried setting the `layout_height` to `_wrap\_content_` , but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to ur linear layout

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: I added it, and now the ListView is being shown; but it's not showing all the items. Only the first 7 (out of 18 total).

Comment: Can you see the other items using scroll?

Comment: I can see the other items on the emulator in Eclipse, but not on the device itself. I can't scroll on the device either. I've tried putting the ListView in a ScrollView, but that still didn't work.

Comment: Never put a listview inside of a scroll view

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Android API, and was trying it as a hack to see if I can get the other 11 items to show.

Comment: You can have a look on this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html